# Can Elasticsearch search by geo distance and other attributes at the same time?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, when I search by geo-distance to a point, can I at the same time filter by another attribute, such as a number being within a range, so that both filters need to be true for the result to come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query, where you can specify multiple clauses in `must` and (or) `filter` blocks. Be aware that clauses in `must` block will contribute to the relevance score and clauses in `filter` block will not ([read more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) about query and filter context).

For example, query that at same time search by geo-distance with contribution to score and filter an age being within a range without contribution to score:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { 
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100km",
            "pin.location": {
              "lat": 38.889248,
              "lon": -77.050636
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { 
          "range": {
            "age": {
              "gte": 18,
              "lte": 65
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```